# Argument is of length zero in foreach loop in R?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

When I run a program, it returns an error on this line:

```
foreach(icount(30), .combine = c, .packages = "mvtnorm", .export = "AddItemDoubling") %dopar% {
    my_day <- rmvnorm(paths, expected_returns, corr_mat, method="chol")
    AddItemDoubling(my_day)
}
```

`AddItemDoubling` adds to a list. I'm using the `mvtnorm`, `parallel` and `foreach` packages.

The error is: **Error in { : task 1 failed - "argument is of length zero"**

The same code works when it's in a regular for loop:

```
for(i in 1:30) {
    my_day <- rmvnorm(paths, expected_returns, corr_mat, method="chol")
    AddItemDoubling(my_day)
}
```

I suspect that the error might be because the code in the foreach only adds to a completely external list? Not sure if that makes sense...

Thanks!

Comment: A `foreach` loop is not the same as a `for` loop. It's more similar to an `apply` loop, i.e., it got a return value. You can't add to a list with it. And why would you want to? Just have it return `my_day` and use the default for `.combine`, which will result in a list. Please read the `foreach` vignettes.

Comment: I get this error when I forget to include the package "mlr" in .packages.  Might not be the case for you, but maybe someone else searching this error.